# How to count number of functions attached to an action hook?

Tags: functions, actions, notifications

I have some actions like this

```
    function simple_notification() {
    echo '<div>This is a notification</div>';
    }
    add_action( 'site_notices', 'simple_notification' );

    function simple_notification2() {
    echo '<div>This is a notification</div>';
    }
    add_action( 'site_notices', 'simple_notification2' );

    function simple_notification3() {
    echo '<div>This is a notification</div>';
    }
    add_action( 'site_notices', 'simple_notification3' );
```

Now i'm displaying those action by calling `do_action` in my template

```
<?php do_action('site_notices'); ?>
```

I would like to display notice count near a menu link called `notifications` Can anyone tell me how to calculate it?

### Update:

As you can see, three notices displayed when i use `do_action('site_notices');`

So I want to display in the menu like `notifications (3)`

Comment: What do you want to calculate?

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't ask me way but i actually have a function to count hooked functions to a tag

```
/**
 * count_hooked_functions 
 * @author Ohad Raz
 * @param  string $tag hook name as string
 * @return int the number of hooked functions to a specific hook
 */
function count_hooked_functions($tag = false){
    global $wp_filter;
    if ($tag){
        if (isset($wp_filter[$tag])){
            return count($wp_filter[$tag]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but this is an example where a single class would be a much better solution instead of writing the same code over and over something like:

```
/**
* my_site_notices
* @author  Ohad Raz
*/
class my_site_notices
{
    public $notices = array();
    public $has_notices = false;
    /**
     * __construct class constructor
     * @author  Ohad Raz
     */
    function __construct(){
        add_action('site_notices',array($this,'simple_notification'));
    }

    /**
     * simple_notification 
     * a funciton which prints the added notification at the  site_notices action hook
     * @author  Ohad Raz
     * @access public
     * @return Void
     */
    public function simple_notification(){
        if ($this->has_notices){
            foreach ($notices as $n){
                echo '<div>'.$n.'</div>';
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * getCount 
     * @author  Ohad Raz
     * @access public
     * @return int  the number of notifications
     */
    public function getCount(){
        return count($this->notices);
    }

    /**
     * add 
     * @param string $n a notification to add
     * @author  Ohad Raz
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function add($n = ''){
        $this->notices[] = $n;
    }
}//end class
/**
 * Usage: 
 */

global $my_notices;
$my_notices = new my_site_notices();

//to add a notification 
$my_notices->add("this is my first notification");
$my_notices->add("this is my 2nd notification");
$my_notices->add("this is my 3rd notification");

//get the count
$count = $my_notices->getCount();
```

Comment: This cant be correct, It would count other object as well. I think you need to go one level deeper to catch all hooks with diffrent priorities to begin counting like `count($wp_filter['wp_head']->callbacks)`. But shared priority keys keep the number of callbacks one nestled array deeper... Also if they come from a class like a plugin, the array contains an object, with many callbacks inside that object...

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty wide. But here is an example how to show how meny notifications there are when they are stored in an array..

```
function wpse_16722_notifications() {
        // Add notifications in an array
        $notifications = array(
            'This is a notification',
            'This is a notification 2',
            'This is a notification 3',
            'This is a notification 4'
        );

        // Count theme for the (number of notifications)
        $amount = count( $notifications );

        return __('Notifications', 'domain') . ' ('. $amount .')';
}
```

You just echo the function where you want them like this:

```
<?php echo wpse_16722_notifications(); ?>
```